# What's the Best Interface for Entering Canadian Postal Codes on a Smartphone Keyboard?

Tags: forms, mobile, keyboard

Typical smartphone keyboards are modal.  There is usually a basic QWERTY/Basic punctuation keyboard by default that can be switched to numeric/extended punctuation mode.

This works reasonably well until we get to the issue of entering a Canadian postal code of the form "L2L 2L2".  (Casing and the space are unimportant.) In order to enter a code, the user has to toggle the keyboard mode 5 times, making the input extremely clicky.

One alternative would be to provide 6 option lists, (A-Z, 0-9, A-Z ...), but the alpha lists would be quite long, and might not fit on the screen.

Has anyone looked at this problem, and what alternatives did you come up with?

Comment: Can the postal code (or part of it) be generated based on other information (like state, city, street)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 1. Genereal Idea

I'm not from Canada but you could check the possible combinations and just provide the keys that are possible after typing or selecting one character.

## 2. six spinning wheels

[image]

K1A 0B1

Letter Number Letter Number Letter Number

Also here make sure just to display the possible next letter or number.

Comment: I like the idea of making the keyboard context sensitive. It takes the work away from the user and only provides them with the required items.

Comment: I like the spinning wheels idea.  It removes the keyboard aspect altogether, and follows the idiom of date selection on the built in calendar.  It means I don't have to train the user.

Comment: this would be very tedius vs. a plain text field.

Answer (score 3):

Nice problem!

I would try to create a custom control which does one of the following:

1. Bring up the standard keyboard and change its mode automatically with each keypress - letters->digits->letters etc.
2. Bring up a custom keyboard and also change its mode automatically. A different look and feel than the standard keyboard would convey the message that this is a different keyboard that acts differently.
3. Bring up a custom keyboard that has all the letters and digits on screen at the same time.

Comment: I like #3, but that's far more work than I'm interested in.

Comment: I'll award the bounty early next week - let it sit and see if a truly brilliant solution comes up.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult. The entering letters first, than numbers could perhaps be helped by alining the inputs differently. Then moving across, then downward may be understood by the users. Might be worth a test drive.

[image: Letters top, numbers bottom]

It depends, among other things, how often your users need to do it. If users need to input a postal code more than one single time, the learning curve (quite small, I suspect, but still there) may be worth it.

Comment: That's worth a test drive.

Comment: This is great! Be sure to accept either "abc123" or "a1b2c3", filling in the appropriate box depending on whether a number or letter was typed.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative I thought of, and dismissed, was to provide the user with an alternate entry option(along side the normal version) - If the code is "A1B 2C3" they could enter "ABC123" and then de-mung it and have them approve it.

I dismissed it because it violates the "Don't confuse your users" rule.

Comment: I think this is the best option, as long as users aren't forced to explicitly choose one format or the other. (See the [forgiving format](http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/index.php?page=Forgiving_Format) design pattern.)