# Is there a way to simplify the input of a canadian postal code on a mobile form

Tags: forms, mobile, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the Best Interface for Entering Canadian Postal Codes on a Smartphone Keyboard?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14267/whats-the-best-interface-for-entering-canadian-postal-codes-on-a-smartphone-key)

In Canada, postal code are structured that way 
A1A 1A1
A = Letters
1 = Numbers

So for example, iphone users in a mobile form have to switch from the alphabetic to numeric keyboard on each individual input.

Do you have any recommandation on how we could simplify the input process?

Comment: We had this question already:
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14267/whats-the-best-interface-for-entering-canadian-postal-codes-on-a-smartphone-key/14353#14353

Comment: Thanks for the comment - sorry for this dupplicate entry

Comment: Is the spinning wheel mechanism presented in your answer feasible on a html form or just in iphone app?

Comment: There's plenty of Javascript implementations like jQuery modules